# finding a pattern in a set of string

Tags: vb.net, string, ocr, string-comparison

Let's say I have a set of documents that contains a persons name like a driver's license, a passport, an invoce etc,.

From each document I have a process that using ocr(Optical Character Recognition) extracts the persons name from these documents. Since the extraction process may contain errors I need to find the "correct name" in that set of strings.

So lets I have the following strings as a persons name - "John" ; "J0hn" ; "JOHN"; "10hn";"+o-."; "john smith".
As a person you can tell that the person name is John as it is the most common occurrence.
What is the best way to do this? Is there an algorithm to find the most common occurrence in a set of string?

Comment: It sounds like an [artificial intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence) issue. I guess, it can be solved by some kind of [neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network). However, in general, it soudns wrong - very high costs of implementation and learning, high error rate. The best way to do this is to avoid doing this. Make people enter data or, at least, choose and filter the correct results. Finding the most common occurence does not guarantee finding the right one.

Comment: First of all, Thank you for your answer. I am aware that the result won't always be correct but it will be validated by a user before and data is saved or stored. The system has to present a value has the most probable occurrence the user will then aprove or correct the value.